# update followed by "broken pipe", read-only disks, and error

Tags: updates, pipe

Yesterday night I did an `apt-get update` and installed some updates (unfortunately I didn't really pay attention to what I've installed).
This morning when I switch the laptop on, it couldn't boot and a message of this sort appeared:

```
Could not write bytes: broken pipes
```

I went on recovery mode, and I first tried to make free space. Did not work.
Then I tried to run `dpkg`, but the filesystem state was on read-only state. So I changed the state, ran `dpkg`, not really sure of the outcome.
Nothing happened initially, but later I resumed and it finally booted (but incredibly slowly).
I ran Smartcontrol and got this:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi Travelstar 5K500.B
Device Model:     Hitachi HTS545050B9A300
Serial Number:    101218PBN403X7DG2G2L
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 67cd47de9
Firmware Version: PB4OC66G
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 6
Local Time is:    Wed Mar 27 08:04:59 2013 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 119) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  645) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 158) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       65536
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   154   154   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4022
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       7605
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3080
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       266
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       108285
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   127   127   000    Old_age   Always       -       43 (Min/Max 1/58)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       70%      7605         438875110
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7139         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5584         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       878         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       541         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

---

In addition, sometimes when I restart the laptop, it appears

```
[354.899490] end request: I/0 error, dev sda, sector 463582321
```

then I log in, but the graphic is a joke and it's just too slow.

Any help?

Comment: the line: "  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       65536" and "# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       70%      7605         438875110" show problem with reading. You can try to disconnect the harddisk and re-connect it, but I doubt this will help

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive seems to be failing. You should at a minimum back up your data ASAP.

You can try limping along, sometimes you can reformat the disk and get some use out of it, but it can completely fail at any time.

Best to look at replacing the hard drive.